# How to pass Page elements with a type object in Java Selenium

Tags: java, c#, selenium

I use the following method to load page factory elements for pages in C#. I would like to do a similar thing in Java. Anyone has an idea how I can do?

This is the Pages.cs file:

```
using System.Dynamic;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace Framework.Pages
{
public static class Pages
{
    private static T GetPage<T>() where T : new()
    {
        var page = new T();
        PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, page);
        return page;
    }


    public static RegistrationPage RegistrationPage
    {
        get { return GetPage<RegistrationPage>(); }
    }
    public static NavigationLinks NavigationLinks
    {
        get { return GetPage<NavigationLinks>(); }
    }
}
}
```

There is a RegistrationPage.cs and NavigationPage.cs file which all Page Factory elements and the page specific methods are defined.

So with this system I can simply write

```
Pages.NavigationLinks.ClickRegistration();
Pages.RegistrationPage.CompleteForm();
```

like test lines without any instantiation. When I call Pages.NavigationLinks. it automatically loads the page elements and methods.

Is it possible to create such system in Java

Comment: As a sideways approach to your question, if you can, I recommend using [Geb](http://gebish.org). It's not technically Java, it's Groovy, but it runs on the JVM and is my go-to for Selenium interactions (both testing and bots). In this case, you wouldn't have to have a factory method for `HomePage`, you'd just say `to HomePage` (or whatever you wanted to do with it).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not allowed to make any changes on the software/techonologies used. My company prefers to use Selenium + Java to make the project maintainable for the future test engineers. But I'll have a look at the project to see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public class Pages {
        private static<T> T getPage(Supplier<T> construct) {
                    T t = construct.get();
                    PageFactory.initElements(driver, t);
                    return t;
                }
       public static RegistrationPage getRegistrationPage() {
            return getPage(RegistrationPage::new);
              }
        }
```

Comment: I am confused with the reply. Maybe I could not clarify what I am doing. I'll be glad if you have another look at my problem.

Comment: Maybe this is what u were looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is how You could instantiate generic types in Your case classes:

```
public class Test{   
    public static void main(String [] args)
        throws Exception // Just for simplicity!
    {
        Generic<T1> x = new Generic<T1>(T1.class);
        T1 y = x.buildOne();
    }
}

public class Generic<T>{
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public Generic(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public T buildOne() throws InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException
    {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}

public class T1{
    public T1(){
        System.out.println("This is T1 instance");
    }
}
```

But I suggest that You keep Your code in PageObject pattern:

1. create super class, where You hold Your driver and system vise data,
2. create PageObject classes which inherit from superclass via extends (each page/screen is single class).

Here is example:

here is page object with WebDriver variable, and elements that would always be visible on page, like body, head, logo etc.

// this is superclass //

```
public class Page {
    private String pageName;
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @FindBy(className = "logo")
    private WebElement logo;

    @FindBy(tagName = "head")
    private WebElement head;

    @FindBy(tagName = "html")
    private WebElement body;

    public Page(WebDriver webDriver) {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;
        PageFactory.initElements(webDriver, this);
    }
}
```

... and here is child class where You set rest of elements like inputs, buttons etc.

```
public class PageObjectTest extends Page {
    @FindBy(id = "firstName")
    private WebElement inputFirstName;

    @FindBy(id = "lastName")
    private WebElement inputMiddleName;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//button[@type='submit']")
    private WebElement buttonSubmit;

    public PageObjectTest(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am confused with the reply. Maybe I could not clarify what I am doing. I'll be glad if you have another look at my problem.

Comment: In the top of my answer I've gave You answer how to instantiate generic classes. And in second part of my answer I've provided how You could apply PageObject pattern for Page instantiation. Then You might be able to have more efficient way of handling pages, even create them in concurrent runs, make them reusable, simple to maintain. I am sorry if I confused You, but You have to tweak Your c# code a bit different, @Grasshopper also made an valid example also.

Comment: I updated my question. Please have a look. I could not ask what I need properly. Or did not understand how your code would help me without instantiation.